# use swift file into Objective-C project

Tags: swift

Can anyone tell me how can I use swift file into my objective-C project?

I have a swift file which inherits from UIViewController instead of NSObject. I am trying to use the swift file but I am not able to figure out how.

When I add my swift file into objective-C project, it usually asks to create a bridging header.
In that header file I am importing my swift file as -

```
#import "SlideController.swift"
```

and my bridging file name is **`objcToSwift-Bridging-Header.h`**

I read many answers which asks to import file

```
 #import "MyProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

into the .m file, but I can't find any such file in my project.

I also changed the `defines module = YES` as shown in another answer.

But still I am not able to access swift file.
What am I missing? Please tell me the right steps to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created Bridging header.

Go to Build Setting =>Search for "Objective-C Bridging Header"

Just below you will find ""Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" file

and import That file in your view controller.

ex.In my case: "Dauble-Swift.h"

[image]